# File Explorer in Windows 10 showing two Desktop icons

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

This is a new installation of Windows 10 (with the April 2018 Update).  Windows Explorer is showing two different `Desktop` icons with different contents: one empty, and the other not.

[image: File Explorer screen shot]

I have two other computers with Windows 10, and in those computers, `OneDrive` and all those other folders are shown by themselves, not as children of the `Desktop` folder. Here I am also unable to simply drag those folders out from under `Desktop`.

Since I am preparing this computer for an elderly relative, I would prefer not to confuse her with two different locations with the same name. Is this the Windows default, or did something go wrong during installation? Can it be undone, so that the child folders are displayed by themselves, like on my other computers?

Comment: You can unpin the Desktop under Quick Access. Click the pin next to the icon

Comment: That is actually the one I would prefer to keep, so that I can always tell her over the phone how to sort the contents of that folder after clicking it in Quick Access.  I would prefer to "correct" the other one.

Comment: The one under Quick Access is configurable. The other one is default under My PC. The Quick Access one is empty right? You can unpin it and then try re-pinning it to see if that fixes the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By clicking right in the tree menu panel showing following option:
[image]

When you uncheck on "Show all folders" you again get the options: Computer, Libaries and Network!